# How to create tableview cell selection style color static?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create `tableview` `cell` selected to show selection color `statically` upto go another view controller. Now I am facing whenever I clicking the cell its `highlighted`. I want to show statically after selection `cell`.

Comment: I read this question a few times and Im afraid I have no idea what your trying to do.

Comment: See...whenever I have selecetd tableview cell Its should show selection color statically...after I select next cell then first cell selection color should change clear color

Comment: Oh ok, maybe your table is set to multiple selection? Select you tableView and view its Attributes Inspector. There an option in there for Selection. You may have it set to Multiple selection. Change it back to single selection and your tableview will only highlight one cell when its clicked. The other should return to normal

Comment: I cant get you. Please post some code!

Comment: My solution doesnt require code. This is in the storyboard or Xib file.

Comment: But I am making by Programmatic!

Comment: try this one `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;`